# R: arguments in table command must all have the same length

Tags: r

```
> table(X = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1), Y = c(1, 1, 1))
Error in table(X = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1), Y = c(1, 1, 1)) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

I encountered this error when trying to run a `table` command. However, I don't see why such a table can't be constructed?

```
   0   1
X  2   3
Y  0   3
```

Is there another way to construct a table of categorical data where the vectors are not the same length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table` literally requires two variables of the same length to be tabulated. This is the same as similar frequency/pivot/table functions in SAS, SPSS, Stata, Excel etc etc etc. You need two columns - one showing the source (X or Y) and one showing the value (0 or 1).

```
X <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
Y <- c(1, 1, 1)
source <- rep(c("X","Y"), c(length(X), length(Y)))
value  <- c(X,Y)

table(source,value)
#      value
#source 0 1
#     X 2 3
#     Y 0 3
```

There are trickier ways to do this, but that is probably the most straight-forward. One alternative that comes to mind is:

```
table(stack(list(X=X,Y=Y)))
#or 
table(stack(mget(c("X","Y"))))
```